# Why do lighter gases float?

Tags: gas

Why do lighter gases float? What makes them float? Is there a force pushing them upward or are they less affected by gravity.

Answer (score 0):

Hydrogen is the least dense element so it will weigh less than any other equal volume of gas or mixture of gasses that are at the same pressure and temperature. Since it weighs less than the volume of air it displaces it is buoyant per Archimedes' principle; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_principle . Helium is the next element on the periodic table. Helium is heavier than hydrogen, but lighter than other gasses so helium is also buoyant in air. Hydrogen is highly combustible when mixed with air. But helium is inert and does not combust when mixed with air so it is the most common gas used in floating balloons for safety reasons.